# Opening encrypted volumes using a script

Tags: shell-script, cryptsetup

I have two encrypted volumes that I use occasionally. One is a partition and the other is a container file. I always use them at the same time.

I currently open them using something like this:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup -y open --type plain /dev/sda4 v1
$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/v1 /mnt/v1
$ sudo losetup /dev/loop0 v2
$ sudo cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/loop0 v2
$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/v2 /mnt/v2
```

But it's laborious entering these commands every time, even if I use history expansion.

If I put the commands in a script, is it possible to get the script to ask me to enter the passphrase for each volume?

Comment: Have you tried?  Because that's exactly what it'll do...

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. I should have tested before asking.

I am asked for the passphrases when executing these commands in a script.

Answer (score 0):

`read -sp ‘Enter passphrase ‘ pw
echo “${pw}” | cryptsetup ...` 
should do the trick